# Set value of ngmodel using index in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I have this array and iterate the value using ng-repeat. Using ng-repeat I would be able to use $index which represent the iterator.

Before I have this code where the user input the question order number:

```
<div ng-repeat="q in entries">
  <input type="text" ng-model="q.orderNo">
</div>
```

But the client requested for a draggable feature, to drag drop the questions to be sorted out. eg. the user dragged Question #1 to Question #2 place then their place will change thus the question order number will re-index. With this the user input for order number won't be needed no more but I still have to set the q.orderNo and bind the $index to it when I passed to my api.

```
<div ng-repeat="q in entries">
  <input type="text" ng-model="q.orderNo = $index"> //this is what I want to accomplish
</div>
```

I want to assign the $index to q.orderNo, how would I do that?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
<input type="text" ng-model="q.orderNo" ng-init="q.orderNo = $index">
```

Comment: hi, because of the sortable feature of jquery ui I had to use ng-bind when I reorder the question. But your answer gave me that idea so I will still consider this correct. Thanks mate. :d

Comment: No problem. You might wanna have a look at `http://angular-ui.github.io/` if you haven't already.

Comment: This doesnt work, as you can remove the items, the values of $index does not reflect as view is already initialized. eg: if you add 3 items it gets 0,1,2 and now if removed first and add another the items become 1,2,2